# mongodb sparse indexes and shard key

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding, nosql

I looked through the docs, and couldn't find a clear answer

Say I have a sparse index on [a,b,c]

1. Will documents with "a" "b" fields but not "c" be inserted to the index?
2. Is having the shard key indexed obligatory in the latest mongodb version ?
3. If so, is it possible to shard on [a] using the above compound sparse index? 
   (say a,b will always exist)

Answer (score 0):

1. If `c` is not present, and query uses `c` index in the query plan, then document will not be found because it is not present in the index.
2. Shard key must be indexed and be unique. Also have a look at the notes on `shard key` on [the sharding reference doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/), it says

> **The ideal shard key:**
>
> is easily divisible which makes it easy for MongoDB to distribute
>   content among the shards. Shard keys that have a limited number of
>   possible values are not ideal as they can result in some chunks that
>   are “unsplitable.” See the Cardinality section for more information.
>   will distribute write operations among the cluster, to prevent any
>   single shard from becoming a bottleneck. Shard keys that have a high
>   correlation with insert time are poor choices for this reason;
>   however, shard keys that have higher “randomness” satisfy this
>   requirement better. See the Write Scaling section for additional
>   background. will make it possible for the mongos to return most query
>   operations directly from a single specific mongod instance. Your shard
>   key should be the primary field used by your queries, and fields with
>   a high degree of “randomness” are poor choices for this reason. See
>   the Query Isolation section for specific examples.

so if hypothetically, if mongo accepts a sparse index as shard key, mongo will not know where to place docs which don't fit in the index. One can argue, put them all in another shard for this purpose. Counter argument would be, what happens if it outgrows ... hence I don't think it would make sense to do it, even if it is allowed.

3- I doubt sparse index will work because **shards require a unique index** and a sparse index does not fulfill the criteria. The unique index requirement, I haven't found in docs, but if you use the mongo admin shell help, it tells you about it.

Comment: It is absolutely not true that shards require a unique index.  You can ensure a unique index and use it for your shard, but there is no requirement for it to be unique.

Comment: I still haven't found any documentation which proves or disproves requirement of a unique index. However, while doing the 10gen course, in one of the assignments, there was a gotcha where balancer was not balancing the data, if the index did not have `{unique:true}` attribute. Perhaps, it helps someone.